# HMAC SHA256 in Python: HMAC Library vs Hashlib Produces Different Results

Tags: python, cryptography, sha256, hmac

So I've been looking at Wikipedia's pseudocode for HMAC and it seemed relatively straightforward; if your key size is already the block size, the pseudo code boils down to 3 lines:

```
    o_key_pad ← key xor [0x5c * blockSize]   // Outer padded key
    i_key_pad ← key xor [0x36 * blockSize]   // Inner padded key

    return hash(o_key_pad ∥ hash(i_key_pad ∥ message))
```

This translates very easily into Python:

```
ik = bytes([0x36 ^ b for b in k])
ok = bytes([0x5c ^ b for b in k])

print(hashlib.sha256(ok + bytearray.fromhex(hashlib.sha256(ik+msg).hexdigest())).hexdigest())
```

But this doesn't produce the same result as using Python's HMAC library:

```
p = bytes("password", encoding='utf8')
k = bytearray.fromhex("eae1f9b8c78d0e0dbaeb3bc49fea3f0be9e9dc580c0b0ba09bcf5104713fda80")

x = hmac.new(k, digestmod='sha256')
x.update(p)
print(x.hexdigest())

ik = bytes([0x36 ^ b for b in k])
ok = bytes([0x5c ^ b for b in k])
print(hashlib.sha256(ok + bytearray.fromhex(hashlib.sha256(ik+p).hexdigest())).hexdigest())
```

ends up producing

**1b96a6d3473698c3592a99d752934b875f82cdd623230abc534f92e7b70cc251**
**57dcbe4ada890bcc8d3cc2e6072874e0d1a0d6d3f73ceb1ced8dad4f07b56e33**

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the custom implementation the padding of the key to the block size is missing, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC#Implementation):

> Keys shorter than blockSize are padded to blockSize by padding with zeros on the right

The block size of SHA256 is 64 bytes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms).

The following ptyhon code produces the expected result:

```
import hmac 
import hashlib

p = bytes("password", encoding='utf8')
k = bytearray.fromhex("eae1f9b8c78d0e0dbaeb3bc49fea3f0be9e9dc580c0b0ba09bcf5104713fda80")

x = hmac.new(k, digestmod='sha256')
x.update(p)
print(x.hexdigest())

k = bytearray.fromhex("eae1f9b8c78d0e0dbaeb3bc49fea3f0be9e9dc580c0b0ba09bcf5104713fda80".ljust(128,'0')) # pad with zeros
ik = bytes([0x36 ^ b for b in k])
ok = bytes([0x5c ^ b for b in k])
print(hashlib.sha256(ok + bytearray.fromhex(hashlib.sha256(ik+p).hexdigest())).hexdigest())
```

with the output:

```
1b96a6d3473698c3592a99d752934b875f82cdd623230abc534f92e7b70cc251
1b96a6d3473698c3592a99d752934b875f82cdd623230abc534f92e7b70cc251
```

which can also be verified [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=HMAC(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27eae1f9b8c78d0e0dbaeb3bc49fea3f0be9e9dc580c0b0ba09bcf5104713fda80%27%7D,%27SHA256%27)&input=cGFzc3dvcmQ).